# Selenium Chrome Driver Trouble Selecting or Inputting for Login

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to setup a tool to monitor my Plex account. I am using Chrome Driver to try and login to my Plex account with an email and password. I cannot manage to locate the input fields no matter what I try, whether by ID, XPath etc. I have run a test with the Selenium Chrome Plugin and it manages to to find the element by ID but when running the following Java code I cannot get the driver to find the email and password fields. The extra code is to deal with the Cookies pop up and seems to work, at least it dismisses the pop up.

```
...
File file = new File("src/chromedriver88.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
LOGGER.info("Got Chrome driver - " + file.exists());
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("no-sandbox");

driver.get("https://www.plex.tv/en-gb/sign-in/");

// Sort out the cookies pop up if it's there
boolean present;
        try {
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/a[2]"));
           present = true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
           present = false;
        }
        
        if (present) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/a[2]")).click();
        }

// Wait for log in button to exist
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
WebElement elementLogin = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("email")));

// Send log in details
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));
username.sendKeys("...");

WebElement pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
pwd.sendKeys("...");

// Click log in
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/button")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your email and password input inside a frame:

```
<iframe src="..." id="fedauth-iFrame" 
    #document
```

You need switch it first, use `.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("fedauth-iFrame")));

WebElement username = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("email")));
username.sendKeys("email");

WebElement pwd = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("password")));
pwd.sendKeys("password");
```